# Add debug symbols when linking static library

Tags: macos, qt, static-libraries, static-linking, debug-symbols

I am developing Qt application for macos. There I am linking static lib to executable. I would like to add debug symbols produced in lib's build to the executable. How could I achieve that ?

I am building the library with these options:

```
CONFIG +=force_debug_info CONFIG +=separate_debug_info
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both library and application both qt-based? Are compiling the library yourself?

Comment: Yes, both Qt based and I am compiling library myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **removing** the line

```
CONFIG +=separate_debug_info
```

if you look at the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config) (search for "separate_debug_info") it seems that it does the opposite of what you want to achieve. However that option seems to be valid on linux platforms only.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I have .a file corresponding to static lib but symbols are not embedded in the executable

Comment: @RuLoViC how can you tell the symbols are not in there? Can you give some more details about it? I just tried creating a simple static lib and linking against an app (both Qt-based) and i was able to debug the calls within the library (i.e. setting breakpoints and such). Btw i updated my answer above since the docs clearly state that the option is available on linux only.

Comment: What I am doing is to simulate crash and check the .crash file generated by Apple (I am working on OSX environment) . There, there is stacktrace. with symbols I see file and line number

Comment: Please detail how you create the crash file and how you check for symbols